# conditional statement in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to replicate the MS Access "IIf" statement in my linq query using entity framework.

If Journal.Frequency = "Ad hoc" and Journal.AdHocRecoMonth <> "provided recomonth" then include journals in the list.

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.ID as UserID, Users.FirstName, Users.Surname,User.ADID 
FROM Users INNER JOIN Journals ON Users.ID = Journals.UserID 
WHERE(((Journals.CompanyID) = {1}) AND((Journals.RRDD) = '{2}') AND 
((IIf([Journals].[Frequency] = 'Ad hoc' And [Journals].[AdHocRecoMonth] <> '{0}', 'NO', 'YES')) = 'YES'));
```

My code so far doesn't include the if statement:

```
 var fUsers  = (from u in db.Users from j in u.Journals
                where j.CompanyID == companyID
                where j.RRDD == RRDD
                select u).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a translation of your sql query could be:

```
var query=(from u in db.Users
           from j in u.Journals
           where j.CompanyID==p1 && j.RRDD==p2 && !(j.Frequency == "Ad hoc" && j.AdHocRecoMonth != p3)
           select u).Disctinct();
```

`p1`,`p2`, and `p3` are parameters

Another way:

```
var query=db.Users.Where(u=> u.Journals.Any(j=>j.CompanyID==p1 
                                            && j.RRDD==p2 
                                            && !(j.Frequency == "Ad hoc" && j.AdHocRecoMonth != p3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?  I'm not sure because I can't test it.  Add this below the other `where`s:

```
where ((j.Frequency == "Ad hoc" && j.AdHocRecoMonth <> "provided recomonth" ? "NO" : "YES") == "YES")
```

This is an example of [the ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) which is basically equivalent to your `IIF` statement.

Note: I'm not sure if the capitalization of your search terms matters, but it should be something you're aware of.  For instance, what happens if `j.Frequency` equals `"ad hoc"` (all lowercase)...

Answer (score 0):

```
 var fUsers  = (from u in db.Users from j in u.Journals
                where j.CompanyID == companyID
                and j.RRDD == RRDD
                and ((j.Frequency == "Ad hoc" 
                and j.AdHocRecoMonth != {0} ? "NO" : "YES") == "YES")
                select u).Distinct();
```

It will be something like this.